# Entity framework core 2.1: could not be translated and will be evaluated locally

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

A simple query:

```cs
(from user in _db.Users
select new UserObj
{
   DisplayName = user.LastName + " " + user.FirstName
}).OrderBy(o => o.DisplayName)
  .Where(w => w.EndDate == null)
  .ToList();
```

The model class is:

```cs
public class UserObj
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string DisplayName {get; set;}
    public DateTime? EndDate {get; set;}
 }
```

However I got the warning

> warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
> The LINQ expression 'where(new UserObj() {DisplayName = (([user].LastName + " " + [user.FirstName)}.EndDate == null)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Comment: Where did the field `EndDate` come from? Is it part of `UserObj`? How was it initialized? (Do you know the type of `w`?)

Comment: Yes, it is one property of `UseObj`. I already wrote it in the post. It was not initialized.

Comment: So then it will always be `null` and the `Where` does nothing?

Comment: No, I misunderstood your comment. In database, some rows has values but others are null. It is initialized.

Comment: Where is it initialized? You are creating it with `new UserObj` and not setting it to any value.

Comment: @NetMage, you are right. I thought `w` was `user`. I wanted to retrieve the user with `EndDate == null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment by @NetMage. EndDate should be initialized. Added it the error is gone.

```
(from user in _db.Users
 select new UserObj
 {
     DisplayName = user.LastName + " " + user.FirstName,
     EndDate = user.EndDate
  }).OrderBy(o => o.DisplayName)
  .Where(w => w.EndDate == null)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Order of the statements is important. EF Core will only allow non-translatable expressions **(*)**, such as the string concatenation, in the last select statement.

So,

- either reorganize your code so that the select statement comes last (before `ToList()`)
- or add a computed column `DisplayName` in your database which equals to `LastName + ' ' + FirstName` and query this column in your custom DTO object.

**(*)** things that EF Core not yet is able to translate into a similar server-side statement for the different data providers

Comment: I can't add a new column `DisplayName` in database. Can you paste your code please?

Comment: @Hello https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#computed-columns